# Excel create weekday sequence with repeating dates and date increment

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to build a scheduler for work projects and I am trying to ask my photography shoot date column to do a few things but I can’t get them all to action. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Firstly, I would like my first shoot date to read from a date that has been calculated by other requirements of the project. I have just been doing =d12 Where d12 is my start date as I plan to use this sheet as a template for all future projects.

Then I would like this start date to duplicate a further 3 times in each row below as the target is 4 shots per day so I am scheduling 4 shots on the same day and then after the 4th repeat I would like it to change to the following day so:

```
13/6/20 (generated by my start date)
13/6/20
13/6/20
13/6/20
14/6/20
14/6/20
14/6/20
14/6/20
15/6/20
15/6/20
15/6/20
15/6/20
```

And so on until the shots are all planned in.

Finally I would like this all to only use weekdays.

Is this possible?

Please advise I have managed to get parts of it to work or almost work together and am now stuck!!

Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**  *better formula*

Assuming your start date in `D12` is a **weekday** (M-F) (and June 13, 2020 is a Saturday, so it should be June 15), you can use this formula and fill down as far as needed:

```
=WORKDAY($D$12,(ROWS($1:1)-1)/4)
```

If you happen to have Excel O365 with the `SEQUENCE` function, you could use:

```
=WORKDAY($D$12,(SEQUENCE(num_of_days_to_schedule*4)-1)/4)
```

and the results would spill down as needed.

Comment: Perfect! Your first formula offered worked absolutely perfectly, thanks so much that really had me stumped! What a great forum

Comment: @JBlearnsexcel Note my edit with the changed formula that will be more robust, and can start in any cell.  Also, if my answer satisfies your problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as accepted. You can read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
--  A   B   C   D                E                   
 9
10              Day#1            Day#2       
11              
12              13-Jun-2020      =WORKDAY(D12,1)  
13              =D12             =WORKDAY(D13,1)      
14              =D13             =WORKDAY(D14,1)
15              =D14             =WORKDAY(D15,1)
16
```

Tables are fast to build via copy-and-paste (`Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-V`) because Excel handles the formulae for you.
You manually enter cell `D12` and `E12`.
You enter `D13` and copy-and-paste that cell down to `D14:D15`.
Then copy-and-paste the `E12` cell down to `E13:E15`.
You could copy the whole `E:E` column across as many times as needed.

Maybe you also want more precison by swapping `D13`'s formula to `=D12+TIME(6,0,0)` etc ([help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/time-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457))

Comment: Thank you for this, I’ll need to spend a bit of time getting my head around this and testing it out as I’m a fairly new self learner! Really appreciate the help!